Are there past polls in the US on whether the current election was then deemed "the most important election of their lifetime"?
CNN:

More than two-thirds of likely voters believe that this is the most important election of their lifetime, including 72% of Trump supporters and 70% of Harris’ backers. The 5% of voters who are currently undecided will determine which of them walks away from this election happy.
Ironically, only 24% of those undecided voters agree that this election is the most important of their lifetime.

I'm curious if most people in the US always said that the current election was "the most important election of their lifetime". I.e., are there any past polls on the eve of prior elections to compare that one with?

It is interesting to see that so many people think that. Until recently, the election was exactly the same candidates as in 2020—Biden versus Trump. Now, it's still "a candidate politically much like Biden (Harris) versus Trump." So one might think it would be a tie for most people, at best.

Might have to do with polarization. If the differences would be smaller, if the middle class would be larger, if media in the US wouldn't give so much focus on extreme positions (surely there almost always is a middleground), maybe elections would be normal important, but not that important.

Also, the world did not end because of the results of the previous elections. It COULD still end because of the results of the next election. So it is the most important ever. People have an amazing capacity for forgetting things.

I suspect that it is frequent that press articles and voter registration drives talk up that "This election is very, very, important. ".

The 1964 presidential election comes to mind. Democrats treated Barry Goldwater (the Republican candidate) as an ultra-ultra-right conservative and Goldwater did not do much to quash that impression. Like 2024, this too was touted as an election of a lifetime. LBJ won the 1964 election by a landslide.

@SJuan76 It also could still end because of the result of a previous election. I mean world history isn't set to 0 whenever a new person takes office. Like the perception of the U.S. by other countries, including sympathies, antipathies and fears, might be set by former presidents. Similarly the climate doesn't care if the new president is green when for the last decades they very much weren't. So shit could also blow up with a delay. For example in a time where one would have needed global action on climate change Trump encouraged nationalist imperialism not just in the U.S.

I've been voting for 45 years. I can't recall it being emphasized nearly as much until the 2020 election.

Yes, there are a few examples. It's a phrase which is often employed by both major parties to get their voting base to turn out to the polls. A few polls were conducted on this issue during some of the most recent elections.
2020
YouGov:

In a YouGov poll of more than 6,500 Americans, about seven in 10 (69%)
people say that the upcoming 2020 presidential election is the most
important one of their lifetime so far.
About one in seven (14%) US adults say that some other presidential
election was more consequential.

Navigator Research:

Nearly nine in ten Americans agree that the 2020 presidential election
is the most important in their lifetime.

Two in three Biden voters
(66%) and three in five (60%) of Republicans strongly agree with the
statement, while only 29% of independents strongly agree.


Post-election, feelings seemed to subside a bit according to the American Survey Center:

Despite record-breaking voter turnout in 2020, relatively few
Americans believe the 2020 presidential election was the most
important election in their lifetime. Overall, 28 percent of Americans
believe the 2020 election was the single most important contest in
their lifetime. Thirty-eight percent say it was more important than
other recent elections, but not the most important. Twenty-eight
percent believe it is no more important than other elections, and 4
percent say it is less important than most other elections.

2008
CBS News:

If the election were held today, a majority of 17 to 29-year-olds (54
percent) say they'd vote for the Democratic candidate, while 32
percent would vote Republican.
[...]
Most say the 2008 presidential election is the most important, or one
of the most important, in their lifetime.

2004
Newsweek:

In the new poll, fully 77 percent of Kerry voters say Nov. 2 is the
"single most important election" of their lifetime (37 percent), or
more important than most other elections (40 percent). In comparison,
27 percent of Bush supporters view this as the single most important
election of their lifetime, while 35 percent view it as more important
than most other elections. Thirty-five percent of Bush supporters and
21 percent of Kerry supporters say this election is about as important
as any other.

There is also a reference in this 2018 article to an ABC News poll where 74% of Americans reported that the 2004 election was the most important of their lifetime.

See this Slate article, which tells us that the phrase 'most important election' has been used as far back as 1805. Politicians do love their trauma drama, so I suppose this is to be expected.
It's more pronounced this election cycle, because both campaigns have made the threat of the other campaign a central feature of their messaging. That's a deep misfortune, and something we have to work to clean up.

Yeah, no doubt some politicians might used the phrase about nearly every election. But perhaps not everyone agreed as much. Hence my quest[ion] for past polls on this issue.

@IVFcomesfromthetip: I don't think that question has appeared on previous polls, because prior to this cycle no campaign made it a central platform. It was just a phrase acknowledged (and accepted) as hyperbole. Generally pollsters will ask what citizens think are the most important issues to them, and get a range of answers. But prior to this election cycle 'democracy' never appeared on the list, because no campaign made a core message of it. This is the US' first real flirtation with fascism; we have to expect some new issues.
